# Theme Development: Starter Content after hook

Tags: theme-development, themes, hooks, add-theme-support, custom-content

I'm making a Wordpress theme that generate placeholder menus using the theme support "starter content". I read the documentation and is very vague: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/30/starter-content-for-themes-in-4-7/.

I want in my theme generate menus and them put images in each menu item using the plugin [Menu Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-image/). But I can't find a hook that executes after starter content generation and executes only once. The hooks I use the content is basically in customizer changeset and I can't access them using the normal Nav Menu API of WordPress.

What I can do in this case. Someone have some idea about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making this part a plug-in for the theme. Then, look at all the code the source plugin provides. I am unfamiliar with this one but it looks to be ok. Find the actions and filters it introduces and use those to build your plugin. In fact I think on  `init` you could do certainly add content.

Comment: None taken! The starter content is a theme support, I don't see reason that would be a plugin. What's the objective? The problem is which hook I should use. Being in the theme or in a plugin, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Based on the fact that the content relies on another plugin this is the best approach.

Comment: Of course you could use the instruction you provided in your theme based on if that plugin exists. The instruction you provided is not vague. Maybe there is a more specific dilema I’m not seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @NathanPowell! I think there's no native solution for this. Well. I understand your view for make a plugin. But I think I will do like storefront does, create a flag for theme to see if the starter content was applied, then select the menus and set the image using the normal WordPress API to does that. I think is a very specific thing I want (maybe it's too advanced) and I have to develop myself. If I dig something I post here. Thank you!